# Symfony 5 Syntax for FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect?

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I upgraded my env from symfony 4.4 to 5.4, and after this I get now the following error:

> The controller for URI "/" is not callable: Controller "FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect" does neither exist as service nor as class.

If I use other urls like /admin/dashboard it works all well.

I have this entry in my routes.yaml which seems to be the origin:

```yaml
dwbn_login_target:
  path: /
  defaults:
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
    route: sonata_admin_dashboard
    permanent: false # this for 301path: /
```

How would one achieve the `FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect` in symfony 5?

Comment: If I adjust the _controller value like this, it works, but seems very unelegant: ```_controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController:redirectAction``` - is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way in Symfony 5 is documented here:

https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/routing.html#redirecting-to-urls-and-routes-directly-from-a-route

In your case:

```yaml
dwbn_login_target:
    path: /
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController
    defaults:
        route: 'sonata_admin_dashboard'
        permanent: false
```